# iOS-Charts null data point do not show on chart

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts

Like the Health app on iOS 8 where null/empty data points are not displayed while X axis labels are still there. Using [iOS-Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) as the chart library for my project is it possible to achieve the same?

Comment: You can achieve this with core-plot. I haven't used iOS-Charts so can't tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't pass a nil, it does not a accept a nil and Xcode will warn about it. What you should do, is just not pass it at all.

**You do not have to pass a y value for every x index. You just have to make sure that the y values are ordered according to the x indices.**

Comment: i have skipped values at index 3 but steel it draws graph....i tried it with filled line chart, i.e. area chart

Comment: How to pass separate arrays for X and Y axes ? Can you please post a sample which can help ? I have read this everywhere but still couldn't figure out how to achieve it. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using iOS-Charts. I am currently making a project which requires various multiple line charts, multiple bar charts and line charts. Even if I have null values X axis labels are still there. You can ask me if you have any doubts.

Comment: ChartDataEntry(value: nil, xIndex: 0) is a sample instance where value is nil. How did you achieve passing nil without any error? I managed to address the issue above but I am curious how you did it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function I wrote based on daniel.gindi's answer (I pass NaNs for the entries in the values array that are empty) :

```
func populateLineChartView(lineChartView: LineChartView, labels: [String], values: [Float]) {
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<labels.count {
        if !values[i].isNaN {
            let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: Double(values[i]), xIndex: i)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }
    }

    let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Label")
    let lineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: labels, dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
    lineChartView.data = lineChartData
}
```

Comment: thank you! it turns out `Double.nan` is also the answer for Apple’s new Charts library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the axis Maximum, so even if you don't have ChartDataEntry for that events it will still show

```
   chartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = 60
   chartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = 90
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer as Daniel mentioned is to just not pass the y value. Initially I was also confused as all functions needed x and y. This approach is how I did it

```
var dataEntries = [ChartDataEntry]()

for (iterating a source array){

   let entry =  ChartDataEntry()

   if (some condition to check yValue exists) {
                                            
       entry.x = xValue
       entry.y = yValue
   }
   else
   {
       entry.x = xValue
   }
                
   dataEntries.append(entry)
}
```

Comment: By not supplying value to y its defaulting to 0.0. open class ChartDataEntryBase: NSObject
{
    /// the y value
    @objc open var y = 0.0 }